# Discord.JS V12 mentioning a user midstentance

Tags: discord.js

So I updated my bot to V12 in V11 the `+message.author.username+` mentions the user but in V12 in does not. I have a command that says `Person: Donated 10 coins to @user` in V12 using the `+message.author.username`only has it say `Person: DOnated 10 coins to user`

Here is the code

```
const Jwork = require('../../beg.json');
  const JworkR = Jwork[Math.floor(Math.random() * Jwork.length)];
  var random = Math.floor(Math.random() * 20) + 3;
  let curBal = bal[message.author.id].balance 
  bal[message.author.id].balance = curBal + random;
  fs.writeFile('././database/balance.json', JSON.stringify(bal, null, 2), (err) => {
    message.channel.send(`
    **${JworkR}** has donated ${random} coins to ` +message.author.username+ `!`)
    if (err) console.log(err)
  });
```

Do I need to do something in order to have it mention a user?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
"<@" + msg.author.id + ">"
`<@${msg.author.id}>`
```

Works, you could also do `msg.reply()` but it sorta has a fixed formatting